# Cakephp problems comparing current date from data on db

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to get all projects with same end_date today, so my codes are below, but i only returns null. Is there something wrong with my condition?

```
$duestoday = $this->Projects->find('all',
  array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'Projects.id' > 0,
      'DATE(Projects.end_date)' => 'CURDATE()'
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: if you want all records why is there `'Projects.id' > 0`

Answer (score 1):

`'Projects.id' > 0` this is not valid array item. Cakephp converts `CURDATE()` to string, Your query should look like:

```
$duestoday = $this->Projects->find('all',
  array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'Projects.id > 0',
      'DATE(Projects.end_date) = CURDATE()'
    )
  )
);
```

condition `'Projects.id > 0'` is not even neccessary.

```
$duestoday = $this->Projects->find('all',
  array(
    'conditions' => array(
      'DATE(Projects.end_date) = CURDATE()'
    )
  )
);
```